# My hive 1.2.1 crashes when i try to run any complex query that requires a M-R job and the OS (ubuntu 16.4) logs off to the lock screen.

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am suspecting a memory/ heap size problem. can anyone help where to look please? A complete hive newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

check hive.log file for errors or exceptions. Hive log file setting can be found in hive conf/hive-log4j.properties file.